# Scraping web page with javascript - Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101

Tags: javascript, vba, scripting

I want to extract a table from this [url](https://es.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::5%7Cexchange::a%7Csector::a%7Cindustry::a%7CequityType::a%7Ceq_market_cap::110630000,1990000000000%3Ceq_market_cap;1) and I’ve got two issues:

1. Before I get the table I need to update the columns which are changed by clicking the gear next to the Vol. Column and need to set as per the picture then click “Aceptar”. [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWBkG.png)

When I try to run my script to "click" the gear I’ve got the following error
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNRko.png)

2. Assuming the previous issue is solved, how can I grab the table? Should I rerload the page?
   Here the code:

```
Sub table ()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy
    Url = "https://es.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::5|sector::a|industry::a|equityType::a|exchange::a|eq_market_cap::110630000,1990000000000%3Ceq_market_cap;1"
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate Url
    Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set html = ie.document
    Set CurrentWindow = html.parentWindow
    Call CurrentWindow.execScript("columnsSettings_stock_screener.colSelectIconClick(event)") 'This line brings the error
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use execScript to execute the onclick function then loop and de-select unwanted items to enable selecting the items you want.

Please ask a separate question about scraping the table. Get this bit working first but note it has a nice clear id you can use resultsTable so I would simply grab with `ie.document.querySelector("#resultsTable")` and use [clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63758380/6241235) to transfer the `.outerHTML` so table copy paste to Excel.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub table()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, i As Long, url As String
    
    url = "https://es.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::5|sector::a|industry::a|equityType::a|exchange::a|eq_market_cap::110630000,1990000000000%3Ceq_market_cap;1"
    
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate url
    
    Do While ie.Busy = True Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
 
    ieDocument.execScript "columnsSettings_stock_screener.colSelectIconClick(new Event('click'));)" 'or uglier columnsSettings_stock_screener.colSelectIconClick(document.querySelector('#colSelectIcon_stock_screener').click());
    
    Dim switchOffs(), switchOns(), selector As String
    
    switchOffs = Array(6, 7, 10, 11)
    switchOns = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9)
    
    With ie.document
    
        For i = LBound(switchOffs) To UBound(switchOffs)
        
            selector = "#SS_" & CStr(switchOffs(i))
        
            With .querySelector(selector)
                If .Checked = True Then .Click 'vba you may be able to do If .Checked Then .Click
            End With
            
        Next
        For i = LBound(switchOns) To UBound(switchOns)
        
            selector = "#SS_" & CStr(switchOns(i))
        
            With .querySelector(selector)
                If .Checked = False Then .Click 'vba you may be able to do If not .Checked Then .Click
            End With
            
        Next
        
    End With
    Stop
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your script. I've tried it, but I've got the error Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method when is running the ie.document.exeScrip command. If I click it manually, the second part of your script checked correctly the options. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. Did you also try the second execScript command I commented out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `vba` scripting but in line:

```
Call CurrentWindow.execScript(
  "columnsSettings_stock_screener.colSelectIconClick(event)"
)
```

`event` is not defined. If you open the page in your browser and run:

```
columnsSettings_stock_screener.colSelectIconClick(event)
```

in your devtool, you'll get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stopPropagation' of undefined
    at ColumnsSettings.colSelectIconClick (columnsSettings-1.22.min.js:2)
    at <anonymous>:1:32
```

Since you wanna simulate click you can instead do this:

```
Call CurrentWindow.execScript(
  "columnsSettings_stock_screener.colSelectIconClick(new Event('click'))"
)
```

Comment: R, I've tried your suggestion, but I've got the error "Run-time '424': Object required. However I realized I don't need to play with this window as it's only to format the screen view, the data is actually there when I pull the information.